# Installing older version gcc@9.3.0 using brew?

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc, homebrew

I'd like to install gcc version 9.3.0 on my Mac Os Big Sur. I was wondering if I can do this still using brew?

I already have the most up to date version of brew but I would like to possibly downgrade or have in addition gcc v9.3.0.

I followed the three commands below

`brew tap-new $USER/local-gcc`

`brew extract --version=9.3.0 gcc $USER/local-gcc`

`brew install gcc@9.3.0`

but when I do

`brew info gcc`

it still says I have v10.2.0.  Is there a way to switch between different versions? As far as I can tell `brew switch` is now broken.

If there is another way to get a working gcc v 9.3.0 that you can recommend I am happy to try it too. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have the most up to date version of gcc on my Mac OS Big Sur machine via `brew install gcc` but now I would like to have `gcc@9` in addition or in place of it. I have `gcc@9`in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@9/9.3.0_1` but I can't find a way for my system to use this rather than `gcc10`. When I do `brew ls --versions gcc`, it still returns `gcc 10.2.0_4`.

Comment: You should take a look at the directory where the HomeBrew binaries are installed.  For most purposes, the name `gcc` will only refer to the first script or binary (or symlink to a script or binary) on your PATH.  If you want `gcc` to refer to a specific version, you'll have to ensure that the appropriate script or binary points to the version you want.  I install my home-built versions of GCC in `/opt/gcc/v9.3.0` or `/opt/gcc/v10.2.0` (where I don't necessarily recommend the use of the `v`, but it's still what I do).  I then configure my PATH to put the correct bin directory first.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. The gcc@9 is in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@9/9.3.0_1`. Did you mean that I need only put  `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@9/9.3.0_1`, say at the top of my .zshrc?